# Should I still subclass from NSObject for data models in my iOS app?

Tags: swift

With Swift, it's no longer necessary to inherit from NSObject.  Should I still subclass from NSObject for the data model classes in my iOS app?

Comment: Thank you Martin.  Useful link - but my question may still be relevant because I am asking specifically data model classes.

Answer (score 3):

The main benefit of subclassing `NSObject` is that when bridging to Objective-C code, the class will be bridged over. If you have a bare Swift `class`, then it will not be visible via the Objective-C bridge.

You can decide whether or not you want to subclass `NSObject` based on whether or not you want to maintain Objective-C compatibility.

Comment: I want to add that subclassing `NSObject` implicitly adds `@objc` to your class. If you don't subclass `NSObject` and add `@objc` yourself, it will still be bridged to ObjC

Comment: Good point, forgot about that.

Comment: Also, pure swift classes cannot be the target or client of Key Value Observation, which is in my mind, the best way to interface between your model and your views.